# how to toggle css via jquery with the .css function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

the function is triggered via a button so I thought every time you push it will check x set the  background accordingly and put x in the other state so the next push gives the other result

I just saw that I can use the .css in an .toggle but I'm still curious why my solution wont work

```
var x = 0;

function toggledark(x){
    if (x == 0) {
        $('body').css({'background-color': 'red'});
        x+=1;
        return x;
    }
    else {
        $('body').css({'background-color': 'black'});
        x-=1;
        return x;
    }
}
```

I thought it will toggle but I only get black and it stays this way

Comment: Can you post your html also thank you

Comment: How are you calling this function? are you passing parameter x when function is called? If x is global then why x is a parameter?

Comment: The parameter `x` in `toggledark(x)` is shadowing the global variable `x`.

Comment: @ChrisG is right that the parameter in your function is overriding the global variable. Since triggered by a button, you're likely attaching it to a click listener, and the first parameter of the click listener is the `event`, so you're just renaming `event` as `x`. Just remove the `x` from your parameters, and you should be golden as is. http://jsfiddle.net/ntdh8v1w/

Comment: thank you @ChrisG I thought I have to give it to the function

Comment: just did, thx for the explanation @mark.hch

Comment: @Hisfantor Yeah, that's a common misconception. The parameter name you use in the declaration of the function is used to access the values that were passed into the function call. So if you had a call like `toggleDark("hello");` somewhere in your code, the `x` inside your function would be `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: I don't think this is a good solution, I would do it with classes, but I'll provide the code for your question if you want to do it this way**

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ygrebp2/3/

I would do it like that since you are using Jquery:

HTML:

```
<button class="toggle">
Click me
</button>
```

JQuery:

```
var x = 0;

$('body').on('click', '.toggle', function(){
    if(x == 0){
        $('body').css('background-color', 'black');
    x+=1;
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
    x-=1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for `x` as integer unless you have another actions to do .. But while you using `red` and `black` you can use it like this

```js
var color = 'red';   // default background color
function toggledark(){
   color = (color == 'red') ? 'black' : 'red';
   $('body').css({'background-color': color });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="toggledark()">Toggle</button>
```

AND if you have another actions to do and you must use if statement for it you can use it like

```js
var color = 'red';   // default background color
function toggledark(){
   color = (color == 'red') ? 'black' : 'red';
   $('body').css({'background-color': color });
   if(color == 'red'){
      console.log('Red Theme');
   }
   if(color == 'black'){
      console.log('Black Theme');
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="toggledark()">Toggle</button>
```